# How do i calculate an average time using standardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

At the moment I have a column in a table with this information:

For example:

```
00:11:35
00:20:53    
00:17:52    
00:06:41
```

And I need to display the average of that time.

These times would give an average of 00:14:15.

How to do that?

Ah, I'm trying to display this in Metabase, so I'd need a conversion form where after averaging the time it was converted to string.

So maybe it's not that simple.

The structure of field is:

Table Field: tma (type time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIME '00:11:35' tma UNION ALL
  SELECT '00:20:53' UNION ALL    
  SELECT '00:17:52' UNION ALL    
  SELECT '00:06:41' 
)
SELECT 
  TIME_ADD(TIME '00:00:00', INTERVAL CAST(AVG(TIME_DIFF(tma, TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)) AS INT64) SECOND) average_time,
  FORMAT_TIME('%T', TIME_ADD(TIME '00:00:00', INTERVAL CAST(AVG(TIME_DIFF(tma, TIME '00:00:00', SECOND)) AS INT64) SECOND)) average_time_as_string
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row average_time    average_time_as_string   
1   00:14:15        00:14:15
```