# How to find, average of time in BigQuery grouped by a column?

Tags: google-bigquery, average

I have the below columns in table **job_stats**. job_end_time is TIME datatype on which BQ doesn't seem to allow usage of average function directly. I am using Standard SQL and trying to find the average end time of each job.

> job_name  run_date  job_start_time job_end_time
>
> ---
>
> A         2020-08-03       15:30:00     15:40:00
>
> A         2020-08-10       15:40:00     16:00:00
>
> B         2020-08-01       09:00:00     09:20:00
>
> B         2020-08-08       09:30:00     10:00:00

Expected output:

### job_name  avg_end_time

A           15:50:00

B           09:40:00

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i calculate an average time using standardSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52975901/how-do-i-calculate-an-average-time-using-standardsql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL 
SELECT job_name, 
  FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(
    '%T', 
    TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(CAST(AVG(TIME_DIFF(job_end_time, '00:00:00', SECOND)) AS INT64))
  ) AS avg_end_time 
FROM `project.dataset. job_stats`
GROUP BY job_name
```

if to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row job_name    avg_end_time     
1   A           15:50:00     
2   B           09:40:00
```